# Putting data from a core database in an array

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a core data database and I would like to show the data into a tableview.
I have been searching on the web how to do that but I never can find it.

```
NSEntityDescription *entitydesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Host" inManagedObjectContext;context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:entitydesc];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

But I have no idea what I have to write in the predicateWithFormat so I can select all the data of my database table.

And when I have all the data of my database table how can I put them in an array so i can add the array to a tableview?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the `NSFetchRequest` docs:

> If you don’t specify a predicate, then all instances of the specified
>   entity are selected

Comment: Ok thanks :) that works :) but It will only add the last data so in my table view I have just 1 row and in my database are 3 rows

Comment: that will fetch all objects of that entity type, so if it only returns 1 item, you only have 1 item of that entity in core data

Comment: but i want the data in my entity

Comment: I have it :) I used an NSArray but I had to use an NSMutableArray :) Thanks for your help